# Triggering component from outside

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

So I am trying to create a re-usable modal component. How can I acctually pass the toggleModal `v-if` thing to be triggered from outside the component? Also, I do not want a situation, where I got 2 modals in one components, and by triggering one, it opens all of them instead of only the one I clicked on. How should I approach this?

```html
<div class="modal" v-if="toggleModal">
..content
</div>
```

```js
 props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Title',
    },
  },
  setup() {
    let toggleModal = ref(true)

    return { toggleModal }
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add another prop that is toggleModal and that way when it's changed in the parent it's directly changed in the child
In the parent component:

```
<template>
    <Modal :toggleModal="toggleModal1" v-on:ok="toggleModal1=false" />
    <Modal :toggleModal="toggleModal2"/>
</template>

data() {
    return{
        toggleModal1: false,
        toggleModal2: true,
    }
}
```

In the child component:

```
 props: {
    title: {
      type: String,
      default: 'Title',
    },
    toggleModal: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
  },
```

Comment: Thanks, but will this not trigger all modals on the page? Is there way to make the toggleModal thing to be unique each time, or any other way to do it?

Comment: @MotahBoat Of course it will be unique it depends on what you pass this is the right way I edited the answer for an example

Comment: Could you help me with one more thing, after clicking ok button in my component it doesn't allow me to change the prop `@click="$emit('ok'), (toggleModal = !toggleModal)"` , I do not want to close the modal each time from parent component, but I want this to happen after clicking submit button automatically.

Comment: you're emitting a parent event because that should be the solution ? i didnt really understand